# Authorization bearer token with NEST elasticsearch and C#

Tags: c#, nest, elasticsearch-net

I've got a problem while trying to connect to an elasticsearch API. 
The API expect an bearer token, but the NEST lybrary only provides a basic authentication and I've got to pass a custom header as well. So, did anybody have to face this problem?? How to pass custom headers?!

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Where does the api connects with elastic. I assume bearer is token for api

Answer (score 6):

You can add headers that should be added to *all* requests on [`ConnectionSettings`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/configuration-options.html)

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .GlobalHeaders(new NameValueCollection 
    { 
        { "Authorization", "Bearer fnoi3nfion3fn00jr0j1r0" } 
    });

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was getting a mistaken concept. Actually I'm interacting with an API wich encapsolate the elasticsearch and just use the elasticsearch query sintax, so I didn't need to use NEST, the elasticsear package, to connect with it. And I just got to interact it with a simple http call.

Anyway, thanks Russ

Answer (score -1):

you can add any header to your request:

```
req.Headers.Add("CustomeKey", CustomeData);
```

Comment: I'm not using httclient or something similar. I'm using NEST, the elasticsearch package, so I can use it. Where did you come with req ???